# Change behaviour of Enter and Space keys

Tags: kotlin, javafx

Currently, in JavaFX, pressing the Enter key fires the default button in a UI and pressing the space key fires `onAction` on the currently focused control. Because I am working on a video processing tool, it is more natural to use the space bar to play/pause the video. Currently, I can assign Ctrl+Space bar to Play/Pause like so:

```
scene.accelerators[KeyCodeCombination(SPACE, CONTROL_DOWN)] = Runnable {
    autoPlayState.value = if (autoPlayState.value != null) null // Pauses playback
    else Forward // Plays the video forward
}
```

I tried to do the same while removing the Ctrl-Key from the combination, like so:

```
scene.accelerators[KeyCodeCombination(SPACE)] = Runnable {
    autoPlayState.value = if (autoPlayState.value != null) null
    else Forward
}
```

but it does not work, as JavaFX prefers to trigger `onAction` for the focused control rather than invoking the accelerator.

I would therefore like to change this behavior and have the Enter key trigger the currently focused control and space bar trigger the accelerator. Is that even possible?

Comment: "Proper" way to do this is to subclass the controls' skins and override their behavior.  That is quite a large undertaking. An approach that is easier and fairly robust is to register an event *filter* with the scene and intercept the appropriate key strokes, processing and consuming them as needed.

Comment: accelerators are the last to see the events, they get them only if none of the nodes in the dispatch chain before them have consumed them - so an eventFilter would be the way to go as already suggested by @James_D (actually, I think it's the only option if you want to not let the focused component handle them)

Comment: I'll try an event filter then, thanks for your help :) If one of you would mind formulating this as an answer I'll gladly mark it as the solution. Cheer s:)

Comment: _pressing the space key fires onAction on the currently focused control_ you are talking specifically about control is-a button?

Comment: actually, the complete sentence _pressing the Enter key fires the default button in a UI and pressing the space key fires onAction on the currently focused control_  isn't entirely correct - the default button is triggered only if the currently focused control does not consume it (there's a bit fuzzyness in the implementation of core buttons, though ;) So you have to specify __exactly__ what you want to achieve: including which controls are in the ui and with/out having a default button. Best with a [mcve] :)

Comment: Well, I think I described pretty clearly what I want: I want to assign an accelerator action to pressing the space bar without any modifier key. This, however, seems impossible, because it instead triggers `onAction`. And it doesn't target buttons specifically. Other controls, like e.g. titled panes, have other actions that happen when you press space while they are focused (e.g. a `TitledPane` expands or collapses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behavior of JavaFX controls is not really public API (at this time), so changing the behavior of controls is generally only a weakly-supported task. Other than re-writing a lot of the skin and behavior classes for the `Button` (and possibly other controls) from scratch, the best way is probably to intercept keystrokes with an event filter and consume them if you don't want them to propagate to the control in the default manner.

This is not entirely robust, and it's not clear which type of key event (pressed, released, or typed) you need to filter, so some trial-and-error may be necessary. However, it would look something like

```
scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        // maybe some logic here to see what has the focus, etc...
        playOrPauseVideo();
        e.consume();
    }
});
```